# Inappropiate search through sqlite database from android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

This query seems to work fine:

```
public Cursor getOneWine(long id) {
    return database.query("vino", null, "_id=" + id, null,
                          null, null, null);
}
```

But when I try to change `"_id"+id` to `"name="+name` it does not work! also tried this:

```
public Cursor getSearchWine(String name) {
    return database.query("vino", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, "name="+name, null,
                          null, null, "name");
}
```

which is working well when I want a cursor from all wines.

```
public Cursor getAllWines() {
    return database.query("vino", new String[] {"_id", "name"},  null, null,
                          null, null, "name");
}
```

Also checked the Android documentation but didn't find a solution.

Comment: You have a crash ? or only no result ?

Comment: It would be helpful to paste the relevant code surrounding the problem you are having, as well as posting any details on the error. "it does not work!" gives no information. You need to state if an Exception is occuring, or the program is hanging, or returning a wrong result. The more info you give, the better the answer you get. Try this link: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: i got a crash "unfortunatly vinos has stopped" it changes to the layout i want but then i got the error, I solved with the anser below but now it shows nothing.

Comment: Is the `name` correct? Does it show up in the result of `getAllWines`?

Comment: yes, getAllWines and getOneWine work perfectly.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Why are you reverting a change made by the OP?

Comment: @interjay, whoops, I only saw CL's revision changing "nombre" to "name", but I missed the OP's revision that did the same, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, strings must be quoted:

```java
db.query("vino", new String[] {"_id", "nombre"}, "name='" + name + "'", ...);
```

However, this will cause problems if the name contains `'`; it is recommended to use *parameters* for strings instead:

```java
db.query("vino", new String[] {"_id", "nombre"}, "name=?", new String[] {name}, ...);
```

Comment: Thank you! the crash is gone, but now it shows nothing with a name that is in it.Excuse me i tried to translate my query nombre=name.